# Any good text editor - Android app - optimised for programmers?

Tags: android, python, lua, scheme, code-editor

Are there any good Android apps - text editors, optimised for programmers?

**I'm asking about an Android app which is an editor!**  I am **not** interested in editors running on a desktop/laptop computers for editing Android programs. Features I am looking for:

- popular programming languages' syntax highlighting (JavaScript, Python, Lua, ...),
- visual matching of parentheses (for Lisp lovers),
- auto indentation,
- touch a word/identifier to start searching for it,
- reading/writing to SD card, Dropbox, github,
- code autocompletion,
- open source.

Any combination of the above would be great, I don't even dream about all of them in one app.

Comment: You should make clear that you're talking about running the editor on the Android device and not for developing Android programs using a PC to host the dev environment (that's what it sounds like you're looking for to me, anyway).

Comment: OK... I thought it was clear, thanks for pointing it out, I'll try to improve it...

Comment: Check out "920 Text Editor".  Its free, does a lot of syntax highlighting for many languages.  Supports tabbed views so you can have multiple files open, etc.  It is one that I use a lot.

Comment: You can use this library https://stackoverflow.com/a/52641368/1770868

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been looking for exactly this, as I'm a Computer Science student wanting to replace my netbook with the Nexus 7.

I've found DroidEdit: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.droidedit.pro

Along with Hacker's Keyboard: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard

I have yet to use them, but they're both well reviewed and seem to be our best options.

Comment: DroidEdit have some adds in the app, and also some performance issues (the app have small freezes when reading files)

Answer (score 6):

(1) AIDE - You can code and compile Android App on Android device. With syntax highlighting and some *intellisense*.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui

(2) AnJedi - General purpose java editor. with subversion (SVN) integrated.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anjedi

Answer (score 5):

There are many text editors but you said you want it for code. Not sure writing or viewing. Here it is:

- [Vim Touch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.momodalo.app.vimtouch)

Comment: Best option. Free, Open Source, Add free